# Default value of fields in derived classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is there a way i can have derived classes override the default value of the base class? In the example below i would need the Hammer.Name to return "Hammer".

```
public  class ItemBase   
{        
    public string Name = "Base";
}

public class Hammer: ItemBase
{
    new public string Name = "Hammer";
}



public class Test 
{
    ItemBase MyThing = new Hammer();

    // Prints "Base"
    Console.WriteLine(ItemBase.Name);        
}
```

Comment: Do you genuinely want to have two independent fields? Are you amenable to adding constructors?

Comment: In constructor you say `base.Name = "Hammer"`. `base` is optional.

Comment: Fields cannot be virtual or overridden.

Comment: @maccettura `virtual` fields does not exists in c#

Comment: I know, I know.  I misread like an idiot

Comment: Thanks for caring anyway :)

Comment: Is there a reason why these fields are _not_ properties?

Comment: @maccettura they could be properties. How would that solve it?

Comment: @Lautaro if they were properties you could mark them virtual and override them in the descendant classes

Comment: @Lautaro also, properties are the preferred way to do what you are doing.  Fields typically should not be used in situations like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need different fields, you need different *initializations* of the same field.

```
class Base {
    protected string name = ""; 
    public Base() { name = "X"};

}

class Derived : Base {
    public Derived() { name = "Y"}; //same {name } field of a Base class
}
```

Comment: OP said they are ok with using properties.  Which would be a way better solution in my opinion

Comment: @maccettura so how would you solve it with properties and without constructor?

Comment: @Lautaro I don't understand why you are placed under such restrictions.  Why can you _not_ have a public parameterless constructor?

Comment: @maccettura i can have constructors. I just thought you said _properties_ was a better solution. But you meant  properties AND constructor?

Comment: @maccettura: *default* value of a propertry, in my understanding is something that required to have initial value, and subject to change afterwards. If you write `const` properties, without field, you're not going to be able to change them eventually.

Answer (score 8):

You might consider using virtual properties instead of exposing public fields (which is considered [bad practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/161308/5056)).

As such, you can (with C# 6.0):

```
void Main()
{
    ItemBase myThing = new Hammer();

    // Doesn't print "Base"
    Console.WriteLine(myThing.Name);

}

public class ItemBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; } = "Base";
}

public class Hammer : ItemBase
{
    public override string Name { get; } = "Hammer";
}
```

or (if you're using older version of C#)...

```
public class ItemBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get { return "Base"; } }
}

public class Hammer : ItemBase
{
    public override string Name { get { return "Hammer"; } }
}
```

Comment: Does this really compile? I get 
Compilation error (line 7, col 39): Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: @Lautaro you need C# 6 or above to use default property values.  If you are not using C# 6 or above (first of all you _should_ be) you will have to initialize the values in a constructor

Comment: @Lautaro you need to have C# 6 in order to use that kind of syntax

Comment: Ah ok! Well i cant use that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Lautaro you can use it, just initialize the values in the constructor.  Also, why can't you use C# 6?  Its like half a decade old now

Comment: @maccettura im using Unity3D game engine

Comment: Its version c# 4

Comment: @maccettura setting it in get would make it inmutable now? You couldnt change the value.

Comment: @maccettura i dont thing so. since calling the getter will return "Hammer" no matter what the value is. No?

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining a new default value in the derived type, you are declaring a completely new field that hides the field with the same name in the base class.

Because fields can't be virtual, the returned field is the one declared in the type through which you are invoking it.

Solution? Don't redeclare a new field, simply assign a new value to the existing field in the constructor of the derived type:

```
public class Hammer
{
    public Hammer() {
        Name = "Hammer"; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying to figure out what exactly is needed while skating around the .NET version restrictions has been a headache but I have a solution.  According to your comments you *can* use a constructor.

In that case this is really easy to do with properties (which are the preferred way to handle your situation) instead of public fields:

```
public class ItemBase
{   
    public ItemBase()
    {
        //When instantiating ItemBase the value of Name is "Base"
        Name = "Base"; 
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Hammer : ItemBase
{
    public Hammer()
    {
        //When instantiating Hammer the value of Name is "Hammer"
        Name = "Hammer";
    }
}
```

And to test just run this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ItemBase itemBase = new Hammer();
        Console.WriteLine(itemBase.Name);
        itemBase.Name = "Foo";
        Console.WriteLine(itemBase.Name);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Hammer
Foo
```

This *should* check off all the boxes.  You now use properties (making your code better), each class has a default value, and the properties can be changed after instantiation.

Comment: You dont need properties for this solution. The constructor will do.

Comment: @Lautaro public fields are a _bad_ idea and a _bad_ practice.  This is the reason properties exist.  Spender already linked this, but [you should take a look again](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields/161308#161308)

Comment: True. Properties still doesnt solve the problem. Constructors do.

Comment: Which is why I asked about constructors in the comments long ago.  However your question is almost the definition of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  I don't care about fake internet points, I just want you (and future readers of this question) to know why public fields are a bad idea

Comment: Well... start a blog? This question and its solution has nothing to do with that.